Massive error when running streamlit error. States that it is missing ScriptRunContext. How does this happen and what is it?
Whenever I run my python file, it comes with this error. It has many different lines and has various numbers. Here is my python code:
import socket
import streamlit as st
import requests
from streamlit_lottie import st_lottie


def load_lottie(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        return None
    return r.json()



hostname = socket.gethostname()

ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

actualip = '{}'.format(ip_address)


lottie_animationlink = load_lottie("https://lottie.host/12c6f46a-c4a3-424d-87fd-d83f8e5907de/EyAGiHD4fW.json")

st.set_page_config(page_title="Ip Address", page_icon=":droplet:", layout="wide")
st.title("This website is used to find you ip address")
st.subheader("Getting ip address")


with st.container():
    left_column, right_column = st.columns(2)
    
    with left_column:
        st.write("\n\n")
        st.write("\nYour IP address is shown below")
        st.write("\n\nBelow is a video explaining how this works")
        st.write(f"Your IP Address:{actualip}")
        st.write("\nInstructional video: [Video](https://www.google.com/)")
    
    st.write("---")
    
    with right_column:
        st_lottie(lottie_animationlink, height=300, key="Water")
    


This is the error that keeps on appearing:
2024-12-13 15:14:12.353 WARNING streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner_utils.script_run_context: Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.939 WARNING streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner_utils.script_run_context: Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.939 WARNING streamlit.runtime.scriptrunner_utils.script_run_context: Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.988 
  Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
  command:

    streamlit run c:/Users/#####/#####/#####/#####/show.py [ARGUMENTS]
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.989 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.997 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.998 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.998 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.998 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.998 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.999 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.999 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:13.999 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:14.000 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:14.000 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:14.701 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:14.701 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:14.709 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.
2024-12-13 15:14:14.709 Thread 'MainThread': missing ScriptRunContext! This warning can be ignored when running in bare mode.

There are some solutions online but they are not working for me. There are also also not many explanations for this online. Also, the website doesn't update with new code when you reload it, and you have to run the file again.
